# Adding a servers to a domain affects GUI performance of the Server

Tags: performance

A very strange situation, we have the following setup.

3 x Terminal servers ( two are 2003 and one 2008R2)
1 x App Server
1 X DC AD
1 X SQL

Here's the funny part, all the servers seem to have performance issues with the GUI, Even from the physical server it self, if you work in the OS it is incredibly slow, click and wait for responses up to 2 minutes,

( the hardware is not an issue there is ample resources and the performance is isolated to the OS, as SQL and APPS run fine and no performance issues but the OS is dog slow.

I have tried re-installs and virus scanning, i took a new server running perfectly and added it to the domain within 4-6 days the server slowed down exactly like the rest.

The GPO's are simple and mainly domain default.

Any help would be highly appreciated

Comment: You mean, when you add a server to the domain, even as a member server, performance takes a dive? Do you have your DNS setup correctly?

Comment: Not sure of what is the problem, but possibly group policy is what is going on. Join a member server, create an OU that excludes all GPOs, and then assign that computer to that OU. Use GPRESULT /V inside that server to verify what policies are still applying (after running GPUPDATE /FORCE first)